# Integral representation of simplified factorial division

Tags: integration, factorial

I know that $\int_0^\infty{t^ne^{-t}}dt=n!$ from the gamma function, but I'm looking for a single integral which can represent $\frac{n!}{(n-m)!}=n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-m+1)$ so that I don't need to first calculate the factorial of some large number and then divide the result by the factorial of another large number. For example, the equation in the birthday problem $\frac{365!}{(365-n)!365^n}$ would be simplified by not computing $365!$ or $(365-n)!$, but only the resulting expression from simplifying their quotient.

Comment: $\frac{n!}{(n-m)!}=n(n-1)(n-2)...(n-m + 1)$. It does not include the factor $(n-m)$ because it is canceled out by the factor $(n-m)$ in the denominator.

Comment: If the goal is simply to provide ease to calculations, might I suggest Sterling's formula: $n! \sim \sqrt{2\pi n}(\frac{n}{3})^n$.  You have then that $$\frac{n!}{(n-m)!}\sim \dfrac{n^{n+\frac{1}{2}}}{(n-m)^{n-m+\frac{1}{2}}e^m}$$  Sterling's formula provides very tight results even for low values of $n!$